# Django: Can i link 2 model fields instead of the model class?

Tags: django, django-models

Here is my code below,

models.py

```
class Random(models.Model):
    Random_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    Rand_ID = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Input(models.Model):
    Input_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    iref_id = ?? (To be linked with Rand_ID)
    is_req=models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Im trying to link Rand_ID to iref_id so that for a particular Rand_ID, i can have Many inputs.

I know that i can link Random class using ForiegnKey however can i link Rand_ID in any way?

PS- Rand_ID is not the Primary Key of Random.

All answers are welcome.

EDIT:

Rand_ID has unique Values.

Comment: Does `Rand_ID` have unique values?

Comment: Yes Sir, Rand_ID has unique values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ForeignKey` with [`to_field`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.to_field) argument:

```
iref_id = ForeignKey(Random, on_delete=models.CASCADE, to_field='Rand_ID')
```

Note you can use as `to_field` only with fields marked as `unique=True`:

```
Rand_ID = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
```